# angularjs $stateParams returns a function (?!?)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have a very simple `AngularJs` app.

Here my `app.js` file:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
   'ngRoute',
   'ngResource',
   'ui.bootstrap',
   'ui.router',
   'myApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
   $stateProvider.
     state('home', {
       url: "/{Id:[0-9]}",
       templateUrl: 'html/home.html', 
       controller: 'HomeCtrl'
   });
}]);
```

And my `controllers.js` file:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('HomeCtrl', ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {

    console.log($stateParams.Id);

}]);
```

The return of the `console.log($stateParams.Id)` is `undefined`. While I'm expecting `"1"` (my `Id`).

Otherwise if I ask for `console.log($stateParams)` it returns a function (?!?):

```
function l(a){function c(a){var b=r({},a,{data:Dc(a.data,a.headers,d.transformResponse)});return 200<=a.status&&
300>a.status?b:m.reject(b)}var d={method:"get",transformRequest:e.transformRequest,transformResponse:e.transformResponse},f=function(a){function b(a){var c;q(a,function(b,d){Q(b)&&(c=b(),null!=c?a[d]=c:delete a[d])})}var c=e.headers,d=r({},a.headers),f,g,c=r({},c.common,c[A(a.method)]);b(c);b(d);a:for(f in c){a=A(f);for(g in d)if(A(g)===a)continue a;d[f]=c[f]}return d}(a);r(d,a);d.headers=f;d.method=Ia(d.method);(a=Mb(d.url)?b.cookies()[d.xsrfCookieName||e.xsrfCookieName]:s)&&(f[d.xsrfHeaderName||
e.xsrfHeaderName]=a);var h=[function(a){f=a.headers;var b=Dc(a.data,Cc(f),a.transformRequest);w(a.data)&&q(f,function(a,b){"content-type"===A(b)&&delete f[b]});w(a.withCredentials)&&!w(e.withCredentials)&&(a.withCredentials=e.withCredentials);return u(a,b,f).then(c,c)},s],k=m.when(d);for(q(x,function(a){(a.request||a.requestError)&&h.unshift(a.request,a.requestError);(a.response||a.responseError)&&h.push(a.response,a.responseError)});h.length;){a=h.shift();var l=h.shift(),k=k.then(a,l)}k.success=
function(a){k.then(function(b){a(b.data,b.status,b.headers,d)});return k};k.error=function(a){k.then(null,function(b){a(b.data,b.status,b.headers,d)});return k};return k}
```

While I'm expecting `{Id: "1"}`.

**What am I doing wrong???**

Just to try I changed my state in the following way:

```
$stateProvider.
   state('home', {
     url: "/{Id:[0-9]}",
     templateUrl: 'html/home.html', 
     controller: function($stateParams){
         console.log($stateParams);
     }
   });
}]);
```

And it works! It returns `{Id: "1"}` but unfortunately this is not an option for me since what I described here is a small portion of a much bigger and complicated App (so I'd like to have `app.js` and `controllers.js` files).

**Any suggestion?**

Comment: Wild guess: try removing ngRoute .. unless you're using it .. in which case: why are you using both ngRoute and ui.router?

Comment: No, I'm not using it anymore. Unfortunately removing it doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: Would be happy to take a look with you if you can post a Plunker/Fiddle which demonstrate the problem.

Comment: From looking at the property names that didn't get minified in that function, what you are logging to the console might be an $http or a $resource object. Your real app probably has the injections listed incorrectly, so $http is getting injected as $stateParams.

Comment: may you explain better?

Comment: It works on Plunker so I'm not able to reproduce the issue. But this exercise helped me a lot. I found that I had a wrong injection in my controller: `... controller('HomeCtrl', ['$stateParams', '$http', function($stateParams) { ...` removing `$http` fixed the issue. **Thanks guys!!**